# Close local notification programmatically

Tags: ios4

I show local notification every one minute till user responds. However my application is password protected. If user does not responds for ten minutes and responds to eleventh. He goes to password verification. However he has to close ten notification. Can I avoid this? I cannot straight away cancel all local notifications, he should enter the password to do this. Is there any way to close open notifications programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would delete your app from my iPhone immediatelly if it started to bug me every minute.

**Don't do that. Find some less obtrusive way of letting the user know.**

Comment: However doing that is important. Is there any way to close open localnotification.

Comment: You cannot close a local notification from your app when your app is not even in the foreground. I doubt it's important to show a local notification every minute, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am sorry if i was not clear earlier. I want to close all open notifications when action button of one localnotification is pressed. So it will come to my application where i ask for password. At this time all other localnotifications should close.

Comment: Try calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]

Comment: Using  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications] only cancel local notifications. Is there a way to close the notification itself, programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do so as there is no event available which can give you the control of 'View' or 'Close' button action.You should try to find some another way.UIAlertView with timer can be one way if I am not misunderstanding your problem.There you get a delegate method which can be used to close the alert programatically.